# If $A, B, C, D$ are abelian groups with $D\unlhd B \unlhd A$ and $D \unlhd C\unlhd A$ then is $B/D$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $A/C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

So say I have abelian groups $A, B, C, D$ with the properties that $D\unlhd B \unlhd A$ and $D \unlhd C\unlhd A$  then is $B/D$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $A/C$?

From the third isomorphism theorem, we know that all subgroups of $A / C$ are of the form $S / C$ for some $C \unlhd S\unlhd A$, so we would need to find a subgroup $S$ of $A$ for which $B/D$ is isomorphic to $S/C$ but I'm not sure if that can be done.

If that cannot be done are there any additional properties that I can put on some of the groups to ensure that $B/D$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $A/C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A = B = C =\mathbb{Z}$, and $D =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.